# How to get the azure bot password

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dialogflow-es

[image]I created one Azure bot service and I am unable to find the password for the bot created. I want to integrate the Dialogflow with Teams bot. As part of the process I created Azurebot but I needed password and ID of which I got ID but password is nowhere is seen. Searched a lot on the net but couldnt find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure bot service and I am unable to find the password**

Usually, the Bot secret and file are store in **application settings** in the app service and **AppID and Password** are securely encrypted in **.bot** file.

As per my analysis on referring to @The Bot Framework Team. refer this [article](https://romsbotframeworkarr.azurewebsites.net/2018/07/03/find-your-azure-bots-appid-and-appsecret/).

Steps to find password with reference of above article

1. In the Azure Portal, select your bot’s Resource Group
2. Select  **Deployments**  in the blade to the right
3. In the blade which opens, select your Bot under Deployment Name. This will open up a new blade overview for your bot deployment.
4. Select Inputs - > Here, you can find a lot of meta data for your Bot, including your Bot’s **AppID** and **Password**!

Sceanrio2:

Another way to find App Registration password.
there is another way,

Goto App Registrations -> search with APPId -> Go to Certificates & Secrets -> there we can find the password.
[image]

NOTE: If it not visible create a new and use that into the integration.

Comment: I don't see the password. Attached the image in the original question.

Comment: I have found another way to find password try scenario2 once.